# Updating javafx ChoiceBox when state of items changes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a javafx project that uses a ChoiceBox. I am trying to get the ChoiceBox updated when the state of the ChoiceBox's item object changes.

I almost got it working but one problem persists. When an item's state changes the choicebox shows the updated item but it also shows the previous item's state. So I end up with two selections available for the single item.

When I restart the program only the updated selection is shown. Also, when I print choicebox's items to the console only the update item is shown.

My code snippets so far:

```
public class User {

   private ObjectProperty<Name> name;

   User(Name name) {
      this.name = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(name);
   }

   public Name getName() {
      return name.get();
   }

   public ObjectProperty<Name> nameProperty() {
      return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return name.toString();
   }

   void setName(Name aName) {
     this.name.set(aName);
   }
}



Callback<User, Observable[]> extractor = (User u) -> {
        return new Observable[]{u.nameProperty()};
    };
users = FXCollections.observableArrayList(extractor);
```

I then pass reference to the unmodifiable version of the users list to the UI package and then use it in a choice box.

```
public ObservableList<User> getUsers() {
    return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(users);
}

private ChoiceBox<User> climberChoiceBox;

climberChoiceBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<User>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(User aUser) {
            return aUser == null ? null : aUser.getName().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public User fromString(String string) {
            return null;
        }
    });

climberChoiceBox.setItems(model.getUsers());
```

Any ideas how to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: I believe that's a bug in `ChoiceBox`. Can you use a `ComboBox` instead, or do your requirements insist on a `ChoiceBox`?

Comment: I don't have to use ChoiceBox. I'm going to have a look at ComboBox. Thanks James.

Comment: @James_D Unfortunately ComboBox does not solve the problem fully. The previous state of an item is still shown until I select different item.

Comment: You may need to set a listener on the selected item in the button cell to make that work (assuming I have understood that correctly). Maybe post a new question with a [MCVE] using the `ComboBox`.